How to plot bar graphs with pandas using cut function and interval when NaNs are involved?
I'm wrestling with the following:
I have a dataframe with 2 columns of float values that may include NaNs.
For example:
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'vals1': [10,20,25,15,np.nan, 2], 'vals2': [5, 11, 12, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   vals1  vals2
0   10.0    5.0
1   20.0   11.0
2   25.0   12.0
3   15.0    NaN
4    NaN    NaN
5    2.0    NaN

I would like to create "bins" using vals1 and then plot a bar graph with the value counts for both vals1 and vals2.
The critical point is that I would like to reuse the bins created from vals1 in such a way that the value counts can be plotted and the NaNs are plotted along as a seperate category/bin.
Without the NaNs I can do this:
In [7]: bins = sorted(pd.cut(df['vals1'], 3).value_counts(dropna=True).index)

In [8]: bins
Out[8]: 
[Interval(1.977, 9.667, closed='right'),
 Interval(9.667, 17.333, closed='right'),
 Interval(17.333, 25.0, closed='right')]

In [9]: pd.cut(df['vals2'], bins=bins)
Out[9]: 
0     (1.977, 9.667]
1    (9.667, 17.333]
2    (9.667, 17.333]
3                NaN
4                NaN
5                NaN
Name: vals2, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64, right]): [(1.977, 9.667] < (9.667, 17.333] < (17.333, 25.0]]

In [10]: plt.figure()
plt.bar([str(b) for b in bins], pd.cut(df['vals1'], bins=bins).value_counts().sort_values(), label='vals1', alpha=0.4)
plt.bar([str(b) for b in bins], pd.cut(df['vals2'], bins=bins).value_counts().sort_values(), label='vals2', alpha=0.4)
plt.legend()

This plots the non-NaN values nicely (see below).
Question: But is there a way to dd the NaN as a "category" or "bin" in an out-of-the-box way?


You could modify your approach to use dropna=False in value_counts and the resulting Series' index instead of the list comprehension on the bins:
s1 = pd.cut(df['vals1'], bins=bins).value_counts(dropna=False).sort_values()
s2 = pd.cut(df['vals2'], bins=bins).value_counts(dropna=False).sort_values()

plt.figure()
plt.bar(s1.index.astype(str), s1, label='vals1', alpha=0.4)
plt.bar(s2.index.astype(str), s2, label='vals2', alpha=0.4)
plt.legend()

Output:

Note. I'm not sure why you used .sort_values(), be aware that this will only keep the order of the first Series. Maybe you meant .sort_index(na_position='last')?.

Thanks a bunch for the .astype(str), that did the trick! The sort_values  that I used the call to plt.bar is not necessary at all (left-over from experimenting).
